# .htaccess: Image Redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I was shown this rewrite for getting images to redirect to a particular web page. And it allows for the usage of images on my site and others.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/uploads/(\d+)-(.+)\.(png|gif|jpe?g|bmp)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)  http://www.sitename.com/view/%1-%2/
```

This works great if I try to directly access an image from the address bar and I'm currently viewing my site. The problem I am noticing is if a user writes out a link on another site:

```
<a href="http://www.sitename.com/uploads/123-Charizard.png">Click</a>
```

It will take them to that image, not to the page.

What modifications should I be making to the rewrite so that it will redirect the user to the /view/ page.

EDIT: Another thing I have noticed is when posting an image to Facebook, using the above rewrite, it will not display the thumbnail as it once did. I am assuming this is something that cannot be worked around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$  [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://domain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/uploads/(\d+)-(.+)\.(png|gif|jpe?g|bmp)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)  http://domain.com/view/%1-%2/
```

For prevent caching:

```
<filesMatch "\.(png|jpeg|jpg|gif)$">
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</filesMatch>
```

Comment: What happens when I directly access the image (open new window, paste link in address bar, hit go), it takes me to the image. But if I hit go again, it redirects me to the /view/ page. How can I make it redirect me the first time?

Comment: first time, browser load images from cache, so can't do anything except adding `cache-control- but that increases your used bandwidth!

Comment: How can I go about adding this? And how much does it increase my badwidth by?

Comment: it depends on how much files have that header? but if you want all images have `cache-control`, so images will be loaded every time from server.